# ajax is not sending data to php

Tags: php, jquery

I want to send `FormData` using AJAX to my PHP file but when I click on the button there is an error that `undefined index fname`.

```
<form id="myForm" method ="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" /> <br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" /> <br>
    Email:  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /> <br>
    Image: <input type="file" name="image" id="image" /> <br>
    <button type="button" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit"> Submit </button>
</form>

<script language="javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //alert(4);
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
         var formData = new FormData($("#myForm"));
         alert(formData);
         console.log(formData);
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'learn_form2.php',
            data: formData,
             success: function (data) {
               alert(data);
             },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
          });
      }); 
    });
</script>
```

```php
<?php
    echo $_REQUEST['fname'];
?>
```

Please help

Comment: [Quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console? Is `fname` being sent?

Comment: basic debugging: `var_dump($_REQUEST, file_get_contents('php://input'))`, see what really came in...

Answer (score 2):

Note that `FormData` expects a `form` DOMElement, not a jQuery object. Also note that you should bind to the `submit` event of the `form` itself, not the click of the submit button. This then allows you to prevent the standard form submission. Try this:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); // stop standard form submission

     var formData = new FormData(this); // give the form DOMElement to FormData
     $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'learn_form2.php',
         data: formData,
         success: function (data) {
             alert(data);
         },
         cache: false,
         processData: false
    });
});
```

Comment: i tries this but still not working at php end. it is giving error at php that undefine index fname. please check

Comment: Try removing `processData`, or set it to `true`

Answer (score 0):

You should contruct `FormData` using a DOM form element and not a jQuery object. Something like this

```
new FormData($("#myForm")[0]);
```

It would be also to troubleshoot potencial problems to implement error handler on your ajax call.